# Loop de elementos em Lista, boolean, se condição aceita, criar uma nova lista (python)

Tags: python

podem me ajudar?
Preciso encontrar as empresas da lista **empresa1** que satisfazem a seguinte condição:

> o valor apresentado na ultima linha da coluna multiplo seja maior que 1 na data expecifica

essa busca deve percorrer para cada empresa na lista **empresas1**, ou seja, irei adicionar mais além dessas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

empresas1 = ['BRKM5.SA']#,'ITSA4.SA','PETR4.SA','WEGE3.SA','BBAS3.SA'] #> adicionar loop para as empresas nesta lista (remover "]#" para ter a lista completa

# historico de volume das empresas em colunas
hist_vol = yf.download(empresas1, start="2019-01-01", end="2021-08-19")[['Volume']]

# adicionando coluna média móvel do volume
periodo1 = 20
hist_vol[f'MM{periodo1}'] = hist_vol["Volume"].rolling(periodo1).mean()

# adicionando coluna múltiplo entre volume / média móvel
hist_vol['Multiplos'] = hist_vol["Volume"] / hist_vol[f'MM{periodo1}']

# exibir apenas a coluna de múltiplos
hist_vol = hist_vol.drop(columns=['Volume',f'MM{periodo1}'])

# saida (resultado)
valor = hist_vol['Multiplos'].tail(1).item()
if valor >= 1:
  print("ok") #se sim, incluir o nome da empresa em uma nova lista [] e após finalizar o loop imprimir a nova lista
else:
  print("Não faz nada") #continua o loop e avaliar as outras empresas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa implementar um loop, para isso recomendo usar o `for`, a sintaxe é algo como: para cada item em uma lista,

```
    lista = ['BRKM5.SA', 'ITSA4.SA','PETR4.SA','WEGE3.SA','BBAS3.SA']
    for item in lista:
        print(item)
        # você utiliza o item  da lista para fazer suas buscas agora.
```

Comment: obrigado @gorn, deu certo, consegui o resultado!